# Solving under/overdetermined systems in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra

What is the general procedure in solving systems of equations using R (as opposed to manual Gauss-Jordan/Gaussian elimination)?

Must I first determine if the system is determined/under/overdetermined?

If a system is determined, I just use

```
solve(t(a)%*%a)%*%t(a)%*%b
```

to get `$x$` in `$Ax = b$`

If it overdetermined or underdetermined, I am not quite sure what to do. I think the above sometimes gives an answer depending on the rank, but the solution is not always unique. How can I get all the solutions? I think if there's no solution, will R just give an error?

Context: I am planning to recommend to my Stochastic Calculus professor that we use R in our upcoming exam (as opposed to tedious calculators/by-hand computation) so I have a feeling only simple functions will do (e.g. solve) for over/underdetermined systems rather than [lengthy programs/functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-October/143408.html).

Edit: I tried using `solve(a,b)`, but I think that still doesn't give me all the solutions.

Here is an underdetermined example (R cannot give an answer since a is not square):

```
a=matrix(c(1,1,1,3,2,1),byrow=T,nrow=2)
a
b=matrix(c(1,2),byrow=T,nrow=2)
b
solve(a,b)
```

Comment: Please add an [tag:r] tag.

Comment: In the case you show you should be using `solve(a,b)` instead of what you are doing.

Comment: @Bhas Sorry. I forgot to mention that. I think I tried that but it doesn't give me all the solutions. I think it just gives me the particular of infinitely many solutions that minimizes least squares error or something.

Comment: @Bhas Updated. Using solve gives me no answer. Using the function in the link in the OP gives me A solution but not all solutions.

Comment: `solve` gives you an error message. Matrix `a` is not square which it should be for `solve`. You'd better give more details of what you want. Have a look here [System of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) especially the section `Matrix solution` for non square systems.

Comment: @BCLC updated.  For R you can look at package `limSolve` which provides a function `Solve` (note the uppercase S) for solving non square linear equation systems. Experiment with that.

Comment: @Bhas As I feared, what limSolve gave me was one of the infinitely many solutions.* What I'm hoping to get is the infinitely many solutions represented parametrically which are [t,1-2t,t]. What limSolve/R gave me was the solution when t=1/3.

Bhas, do you know anything in R that gives such parametric solutions?

Thanks much for your replies, btw. ^_^

*> a=matrix(c(1,1,1,3,2,1),byrow=T,nrow=2)

> b=matrix(c(1,2),byrow=T,nrow=2)
> library(limSolve)
> Solve(a,b)
[1] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link I gave in section `Matrix solution` in the Wikipedia article on linear systems  shows how to get what you want.
Define matrix `A` and vector `b` like this

```
A <- matrix(c(1,1,1,3,2,1),byrow=T,nrow=2)
A
b <- matrix(c(1,2),byrow=T,nrow=2)
b
```

The following code will give you the general solution to your underdetermined system

```
library(MASS)

Ag <- ginv(A)
Ag
xb <- Ag %*% b
xb
Aw <- diag(nrow=nrow(Ag)) - Ag %*% A
Aw
```

You can check that this is correct with

```
w <- runif(3)
z <- xb + Aw %*% w
A %*% z - b
```

where the vector `w` is any arbitrary vector.
You can simplify the solution further manually to what you gave; I leave that as an exercise for you. As far as I know you can't get that solution automatically but maybe package `Ryacas` can do it.

You can get what you want by using package `MASS` or package `pracma`.
E.g. with `MASS`:

```
library(MASS)
N <- Null(t(A))
```

Then the solution is

```
xb + N * q
```

where `q` is an arbitrary scalar.

With `pracma`:

```
N <- null(A)  # or nullspace(A)
```

with the same expression as above for the solution.

Comment: ...too complicated. Thanks anyway :))

Answer (score 4):

Try qr.solve(A,b).  That should work for both under- and over-determined systems.

Comment: Thanks Sheila. Need any packages?

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/qr.html There's the manual. I beleive you will need the qr package.